# Error decrypting manifest resource stream using RijndaelManaged

Tags: c#, encryption

I have this code:

```
    private byte[] c1(string a, string b)
    {
        RijndaelManaged managed = new RijndaelManaged
        {Key = Convert.FromBase64String(a), IV = Convert.FromBase64String(b)};

        Stream manifestResourceStream = base.GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("file.Assembly");
        CryptoStream stream5 = new CryptoStream(manifestResourceStream, managed.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[manifestResourceStream.Length];
        stream5.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        stream5.Close();
        manifestResourceStream.Close();
        return buffer;
    }
```

I am getting an error after putting some random base 64 Key or IV...
Here is the error line:

```
        CryptoStream stream5 = new CryptoStream(manifestResourceStream, managed.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read);
```

**error message (System.NullReferenceException was unhandled)**

Is it caused by wrong Key and IV?
Or is it a problem in the file?

Comment: Did you check if `manifestResourceStream` is null?

Comment: Has this been solved? Was this a problem with the `manifestResourceStream`?